# Requireing a value in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockout.js and I'm trying to learn it. In an attempt to learn, I'm creating a web page. This web page has a search field on it. By default, the search field is empty. If a user enters a value and then deletes it, I want to make the background of the search box red to show that its required. When the user clicks the search button, I want to show just a basic JavaScript alert box. If the query has a value, just show "Searching for '[query'". If the user didn't provide a query, I want to show an alert that says "Please enter a query.". Pretty plain vanilla.

Currently, I have a basic form that looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .required { background-color:red; }
</style>

...

<form id="searchForm">
  Search: <input data-bind="value:query, css: { required: (query != null && query.length > 0) }" />
  <input type="button" value="search" /> 
</form>

...

function searchViewModel() {
  this.query = ko.observable(null).extend({ required:"" });
}
ko.applyBindings(new searchViewModel());

ko.extenders.required = function(target, msg) {
  target.hasError = ko.observable();
  function validate(newValue) {
    target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
  }
  validate(target);
  target.subscribe(validate);

  return target;
}
```

I got the required extender off the official Knockout.js site, [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html). Unfortunately, my code isn't working. Why? For the life of me, I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: It doesn't appear that your newValue has a value.  Console.log it to make sure though.  Also you need to register your extender before you try to use it

Comment: If you create a jsFiddle I can show you what I mean it should take like 10 seconds to fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not stated written in the documentation but you need to create your extenders before the time first time you are using it.

So in your case the `ko.extenders.required` call should go **before** the `new searchViewModel()` call:

```
ko.extenders.required = function(target, msg) {
  //...
}


ko.applyBindings(new searchViewModel());
```

And since you are using the `required` extender there is no need to manually checking the `query` in the `css` binding because it provides you a `hasError` observable:

```
 <input data-bind="value:query, css: { required: query.hasError }" />
```

You can also use this `hasError` in your `search` function to display the alerts:

```
this.search = function () {
    if (this.query.hasError()){
        alert('Please enter a query.');
    }
    else {
        alert('Searching for ' + this.query());
    }
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDQd8/).

By the way your original css binding was not working (beside the wrong condition) because you need to write `query()` to get a ko.observable value if it used in an expression.

So the following would also work:

```
<input data-bind="value:query, 
                  css: { required: (query() != null && query().length == 0) }"/>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtWxS/).